# When I press the camera button it zooms in further than it should

Tags: camera

Whenever I go into camera view it zooms in way too much and doesn't even look through the camera. Here is an example:

[image: object as camera view]

How can I view from the POV of the camera object?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using an object as a camera. Which is not the same as an actual camera object.

In other words you don't get to control the mm of the lens, because it's not a camera.

To change your zoom however, make sure it is active and move it like a camera, including trucking it around via <kbd>G</kbd> hold middle mouse and move your mouse up and down (hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> if it moves to fast).

If this is a light, and you need it to illuminate something from the distance you view it at you will have to control that through strength and not location, or you will have the same problem all over again.

My guess is that you think you are using the actual camera, and instead you are using some other object as a camera.

If this is the case:

1. Get out of camera view.
2. Select your camera.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Home</kbd> while in camera view to reset the view